# How to make Javascript run function synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net mvc app, I have button click that points to a javascript which calls

```
function OnButtonClick(s, e, startUrl, progressUrl) {
    Fetch(progressUrl);
    ImportUpdate(startUrl);
   }
```

Fetch and ImportUpdate are ajax jquery to a controller action.

```
 function Fetch(progressUrl) {
        positionDate = ReportingPositionDate.GetDate().toDateString();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("BloombergFet", "ImportData")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function () { lpBloomberg.Show(); },
            success: function (msg) {
                ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
                lpBloomberg.Hide();
                lpImport.Show();

            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                lpBloomberg.Hide()

            }
        });
    }

function ImportUpdate(progressUrl) {
        positionDate = ReportingPositionDate.GetDate().toDateString();
        myProgressBar.Show;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("ProcessImportRecord", "ImportData")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function () { lpImport.Show(); },
            success: function (msg) {
            ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
            ImportSuccessMessage.SetVisible(true);
            ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
            lpImport.Hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ImportErrorMessage.SetVisible(true);
            ImportErrorMessage.SetText(xhr.statusText)
        }
    });
    }
```

Currently both the methods  `Fetch(progressUrl)` and `ImportUpdate(progressUrl)` are called at the same time. I want `Fetch(progressUrl)` to complete and then ImportUpdate to run.

How do I achieve this. Appreciate all help.

Comment: callbacks. use callbacks.

Comment: If you always want to Fetch followed by ImportUpdate, I would suggest you combine them into a single API call.

Comment: thanks James . This worked

Comment: Kevin B  do you have an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your second function ImportUpdate(progressUrl) in the success block of the first function Fetch(progressUrl) like so:

```
function Fetch(progressUrl) {
    positionDate = ReportingPositionDate.GetDate().toDateString();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("BloombergFet", "ImportData")",
        data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function () { lpBloomberg.Show(); },
        success: function (msg) {
            ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
            lpBloomberg.Hide();
            lpImport.Show();

            //Place call for ImportUpdate function here, like so
            ImportUpdate(startUrl);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            lpBloomberg.Hide()

        }
    });
}
```

However, like James pointed out, if you want to call ImportUpdate after every time that Fetch is called, it makes more sense to just combine them UNLESS you call ImportUpdate independently somewhere else, when Fetch is not called first.

BTW, the callbacks Kevin B. is probably referring to are used with the jQuery .post() function, which you can use like this:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second finished" );
});
```

so instead of putting your function call in the success callback of your current Fetch function you'd put it in .done callback like so:

```
.done(function() {
    ImportUpdate(startUrl);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    //handle errors
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `ImportUpdate(progressUrl)` inside your success callback function for `Fetch(progressUrl)`